# How to filter records using patindex without dynamic sql (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server

How to filter the records using patindex in sql server ( without dynamic sql)

for example: 
i have record like

```html
ID Name LastName Indicator
1 xxx     Lxxx     NULL
2 yyy     Lyyy     Yes
3 zzz     Lzzz     No

if @ind is null, i want to display all 3 records, if @ind ='Yes' then 2nd record should filter
if @ind = 'No' then 3rd record only should filter. 
please suggest some good solution and it should not affect performance.

sample:

declare @ind varchar(10) = 'Yes' (can be null, yes or No)
select * from 
(select 1 ID, 'xxx' Name,'Lxxx' LastName, NULL Indicator union all
select 2 ID, 'yyy' Name,'Lyyy' LastName, 'Yes' Indicator union all
select 3 ID, 'zzz' Name,'Lzzz' LastName, 'No' Indicator) x
where patindex('%' + isnull(@ind,'%') + '%', COALESCE(@ind,'%',Indicator)) > 0
```

Comment: Do you have to use patindex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sur why you have to use patindex, but if you don't, this should do the trick

```
declare @ind varchar(10) = 'Yes' (can be null, yes or No)
select * from 
(select 1 ID, 'xxx' Name,'Lxxx' LastName, NULL Indicator union all
select 2 ID, 'yyy' Name,'Lyyy' LastName, 'Yes' Indicator union all
select 3 ID, 'zzz' Name,'Lzzz' LastName, 'No' Indicator) x
where (@ind is null or indicator = @ind)
```

Comment: the above query is modified like : where (@ind is null or (patindex('%' + @ind + '%',Indicator) > 0))

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `Or` and `And` operator in `Where` clause. Try this.

```
DECLARE @ind VARCHAR(10) = 'no' --(can be null, yes or No)

SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 1 ID,'xxx'  Name,'Lxxx' LastName,NULL   Indicator
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 ID,'yyy'  Name,'Lyyy' LastName,'Yes'  Indicator
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 ID,'zzz'  Name,'Lzzz' LastName,'No'   Indicator) x
WHERE  ( @ind = 'Yes'
         AND name = 'yyy' )
        OR ( @ind = 'no'
             AND name = 'zzz' )
        OR ( @ind IS NULL )
```

If you want to use `Patindex` use this.

```
DECLARE @ind VARCHAR(10) = 'yes' --(can be null, yes or No)

SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 1 ID,'xxx'  Name,'Lxxx' LastName,NULL   Indicator
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 ID,'yyy'  Name,'Lyyy' LastName,'Yes'  Indicator
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 ID,'zzz'  Name,'Lzzz' LastName,'No'   Indicator) x
WHERE  ( patindex('Yes',@ind )>0
         AND name = 'yyy' )
        OR ( patindex('no',@ind )>0
             AND name = 'zzz' )
        OR ( @ind IS NULL )
```